# How to get a SOAP post in PHP?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

OK n00b here with SOAP,

Would like some clarification on how to use SOAP.

Question:

I have a Java JSP that posts a WSDL (Looks like XML format) to my PHP script, but how do I get this in the PHP script? The URL for the WSDL will be different every time.

I'm sure it's very simple but just don't see how or am I not understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
try {                                                                                                                                                                           
  if (!($xml = file_get_contents('php://input'))) {
    throw new Exception('Could not read POST data.');
  }
} catch (Exception $e) {
  print('Did not successfully process HTTP request: '.$e->getMessage());
  exit;
}
```

This will read the body of the POST request to the $xml variable and print an error if there is one.

Comment: Never seen this "php://input", does this read the RAW post data?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that the JSP sends the WSDL in a POST request to the PHP script?
If so, have a look at the $_POST array. If you specify exactly how the JSP sends it, I can probably help you more.

Anyway, once you have the WSDL url in a variable in your PHP script, you can have at it with the [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) class.

Comment: Yes this is the route Im talking about, so maybe I could just consume the RAW post and parse it out that way?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the best scenario:

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, $soapOptions);
$soapClient->callYourMethod();
```

But you're likely to hit a lot of brick walls when using SOAP. Here's the [documentation for SoapClient](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php).

**Edit:**

So, the WSDL is POST-ed. Then, you could access it either by using [`$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php) if the XML string was sent as the HTTP body, or by using the [`$_FILES`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) superglobal if the XML string was send as a part of a multipart request.

Something like this:

```
$wsdl = $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;
$wsdlUrl = 'data:text/xml;base64,' . base64_encode($wsdl);
$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl);
```

Anyway, `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` is only available if the php.ini setting [`always_populate_raw_post_data`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.always-populate-raw-post-data) is turned on. Also, if the request was multipart, this setting is ignored, `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` is not populated but you get access to the posted parts using `$_FILES`. And you may, indeed, use `php://input` instead of `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`.

Also, [data URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) may only be used when [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is turned on in php.ini.

Comment: but how do I get the $wsdlUrl? this is what changes everytime the I need the PHP script to handle

Comment: Here the URL contains the data itself: The URL protocol is not http, but data. If the SoapClient class handles this, then that's the best solution.